# iPad app to convert multiple photos to a single pdf

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation, pdf, scanning

Does anyone know an app to convert multiple photos from the iPad Camera Roll into a single PDF?

Alternatively, an app that lets you take photos with the iPad camera and saves them into a single PDF would be good - ability to rotate photos is important as this is mostly for 'scanning' document pages using the iPad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Apple's Pages app to do this. Use the "+" button to add files from the image library. There is a pinch gesture to rotate/resize the images. The files can be emailed or exported to another app as a PDF from the "Wrench" popup menu in the top right corner of the screen.

Answer (score 7):

Even simpler than Pages, you can use iBooks

1. Step 1: Select all photos you want to combine into one pdf within
   your Camera Roll, they should be in the order you want them combined
   in
2. Step 2: Press the share button (the up arrow in the box at the
   top left hand corner of the screen)
3. Step 3: Tap iBooks icon prompting to "Save the PDF file in iBooks"

That's it!

Comment: Just tried this and it's very easy to do.  While this doesn't handle the rotate images part of question, it's a good solution if they are already in the right orientation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create PDF from images is to use the "Print" menu

1. select the photos you need
2. tap on "Share" icon at the bottom
3. choose "Print" in the share options
4. instead of choosing a printer, in the print dialog tap "Share" icon again, now it will be on the top
5. Now, we are ready to share the converted PDF - you can tap "Save to Files" to store the PDF. Alternatively, you can choose another option of sharing - send by email, or with a messenger, etc.

If you have scanned images in your "Files" app, it is even easier - select multiple image files, and in the context menu (three dots button at the bottom) will be "Create PDF" option

Answer (score -2):

Site audit pro

Use it daily for work... Amazing

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! We try to provide more in depth answers beyond one line. Can you please explain why (and if possible, how) this works, as well as linking to it?